# How to start a C# service using TSQL code

Tags: t-sql

I use a C# service on Windows Server which stops from time to time. I'd like to write a stored procedure in TSQL to check if the service runs. If doesn't, I'd like to execute a procedure to restart it. Do you think it's doable using tsql? I've thought of xp_cmdshell but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Why do it using TSQL?

Comment: @Magnus how do you think I ought to do it?

Comment: Figure out why the service stops and try to prevent it? Or write a windows app that runs on a schedule and checks/restarts the service (using windows Scheduled Tasks)?

Comment: Using T-SQL is not a good idea IMO. Write a powershell script, a batch script, a C# program or any other. T-SQL should be used for querying databases mostly, anything else is going to be awkward.